# CAPTURE CHANGE AT SOURCE LEVEL

Tags: oracle11g, etl

Consider a source table(ORA 11g) with BATCH ID 1 with 3 records for day 1.  Say these are getting loaded into a target table. Imagine on day 2 there are 3 more customer entries with batch ID 2. Can I write a SQL query which will be enable the source node to check the target if the BATCH_ID is existing and if not read and process that BATCH_IDs records through the code?

SRC TBL(say day1)

Batch_no |  ID

1       |   xx

1       |   yy

1       |   zz

TGT TBL(EOD Day1)

Batch_no |  ID

1       |   xx

1       |   yy

1       |   zz

SRC TBL(Day 2)

Batch_no|ID

1       |xx

1       |yy

1       |zz

2       |aa

2       |bb

2       |cc

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Hi Sentinel....I guess I found something.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found. Thank you for your help.

SELECT required fields

FROM
"SRC TBL"

LEFT JOIN "TGT TBL"

ON "SRC TBL".BATCH_ID="TGT TBL".BATCH_ID

WHERE "TGT TBL".BATCH_ID IS NULL